# Get metadata from stream music through EXOPlayer

Tags: java, android, metadata, exoplayer

I use EXOPlayer to playing internet radio:

```
allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);// Allocator - класс отвечающий за буфер

// Build the video and audio renderers.

bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(mHandler, null);
dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(this, bandwidthMeter, USER_AGENT);
sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(Uri.parse(samplePath), dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, null, true, mHandler, mMediaCodecAudioTrackRendererEventListener);

// Invoke the callback.
mPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
isPrepared = true;
```

But how i can extract metadata from Stream?(title, track and many other) Server: `icecast v.3+kh`